# Plea to a demon

Tags: riddle, word

I riddle you this:

> Gone! You're absent 
>  Really I miss you, you made me see an inferno
>   
>  Everyone liked you before
>  Even after your descent to
>   hell
>  Now come back, lets have a party!

Hint time:

> gmatht's answer is in the right area. *inferno == hallucination*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the answer...

> Absinthe?

Going by Rand al'Thor's idea with the first letters in each line...

> Absinthe is typically green, in accordance with the first letters spelling GREEN.

*Gone! You're absent*

> Absinthe was banned in multiple countries.

*Really I miss you, you made me see the inferno*

> And from what I know, it is known for causing hallucinations (thanks for that hint by the way)

*Everyone liked you before*

*Even after your descent to hell*

> Absinthe was popular still despite it being banned, and it apparently is one of those drinks that burns when you drink it

*Now come back, lets have a party!*

> Alcohol of various types gets served at parties.

Not confident at all.

Comment: Correct! I'm new here, spoilers do not work in comments? Here is some explanations behind rot13, decode them if you wish: Vg jnf xabja nf gur terra qrzba. urapr gur qrzba gurzr. Nyfb svefg yvar vf zrnag gb or purrxl ^^

Comment: It was a nice puzzle, thanks to you and the other answerers :D

Comment: The "come back" may reference (intentionally or not) the fact that the States did actually re-legalize it recently.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the answer is

> GREEN?

For one thing, this word is indicated by the first letter of each line.

*Gone! You're absent*

> There is nothing green in this puzzle.

*Really I miss you, you made me see the inferno*

> Having seen green makes opposite colours such as red (as found in an inferno) more striking.

*Everyone liked you before

Even after your descent to hell*

> Perhaps this is more about green as an opposite to the colours of a fiery hell.

*Now come back, lets have a party!*

> The Green Party in politics.

Comment: I like it a lot! Not the one i had in mind though!

Comment: Maybe google Greenaway and Inferno?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking

> Moon(shine)

*Gone! You're absent*

> The moon has set/The moonshine has been drunk.

*Really I miss you, you made me see the inferno*

> When the sun is set, you can only see the light reflected off that inferno as moonlight/If you drink moonshine you will miss it once it is finished... and perhaps see the fires of hell sooner rather than later.

*Everyone liked you before*

> Everyone at a speakeasy likes a bit of moonshine.

*Even after your descent to hell*

> Moonset is the moon going below the earth, where hell is. After moonshine descends down your throat, it can cause a hellish headache.

*Now come back, lets have a party!*

> After sunset and a moonrise, partying under the moonlight with a bit of moonshine... now thats a party.

My other idea was

> A green traffic light, which every one loves, but that would ascend to hell (red).